# How to hide some administer option from all users?

Tags: 7

I want to hide some administer options (such us: *Actions, File system, etc*) from all users, including admin (*user='1'*).

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you remove privileges from user 1? if your trying to give the site to someone else but dont want them to mess with your installation, you better off creating another role with less privileges than the admin and hand them that role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another, reasonably easy, option to disable access to those menu items is with

[hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7)

and changing the access callback to `FALSE`.

You'd need the relevant URL path to add the access check to, e.g

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter
 */
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // Example - disable the page at admin/config/media/file-system
  $items['admin/config/media/file-system']['access callback'] = FALSE;
  // Remove unneeded access args too
  unset($items['admin/config/media/file-system']['access arguments']);
  // Example - disable the page at admin/config/system/actions
  $items['admin/config/system/actions']['access callback'] = FALSE;
  unset($items['admin/config/system/actions']['access arguments']);
}
```

See [system_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_menu/7) for other relevant menu item definitions.

Clear cache at *Admin > Config > Performance* to apply.

P.S: As an advanced option, you could add your own 'access callback' and 'access arguments' to utilize a custom access check function.

Answer (score 3):

User #1 is special.  This user bypass all access control, so the only way to make sure that *no* user have access at this level is to disable user #1.  However, disabling user #1 is *not* a good idea.  At one point, you may need to have access to a special user account that can access *all* areas in order to fix some serious problem with your site - and in some cases, the all-powerful user #1 is the last resort.

However, you can approach this by creating a *second* admin user account (name it `lesser_admin`) and give this user account all the administration rights *except* `Administer users` and other rights you want to withhold.  You then stop using user #1 as admin and instead log on as `lesser_admin` when you (or someone else) want to perform admin tasks.

To make sure, you may give user #1 as very long and impossible to remember password and  write this password down and put in a sealed envelope in a bank vault.  That way, neither you or anyone will have access to the user #1 account.  However, when the day comes when you regret doing this, you can go to the bank vault and retrieve the envelope.